# How to load Drop Down list with preselected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

My drop downlist have 4values
1.Await
2.Process
3.Cancel
I'm loading this list from DB..Initally it always display the `Await` in Dropdown,but i need to display the status `Process` on page load and need to disable from changing the list.

**My Code**

```
public void BindStatus()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = obj.LoadStatus();

        Status.DataSource = dt;
        Status.DataTextField = "StatusName";
        Status.DataValueField = "StatusId";        
        Status.DataBind();
    }
```

Can any one say how can i set drop down selected value to `Process` and the drop down should display `process`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
public void page_load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindStatus();
        Status.SelectedIndex = Status.Items.IndexOf(Status.Items.FindByText("Process"));
        Status.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you provide a bit more context?

Comment: @Anzeo after binding the dropdown using bindstatus method, she has select the item 'Process' and disable the status so that user can not change the selected item.